# Problems with JPGraph unable to display

Tags: php, html, graph, jpgraph

I am trying to retrieve the data from a mysql data and show it in a PHP page running a session. The code runs in a separate page. And the data is retrieved as Image in another page.
The main problem is no matter what kind of coding that I put above the default graph coding, it will become a broken image. FYI I have already enabled php_gd2.dll and the extension in my php.ini file is set to the extension folder. Are there any other fixes that has to be made in any of the files?

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'])
{
require "dbc.php";  
echo "<h2>Patient Glucose Data</h2>";

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query_view = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_glucose WHERE username='$username'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query_view);

    if ($numrows != 0)
    {
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_view))
        {

        $print_day1  = $rows['Day1'];
        $print_day2  = $rows['Day2'];
        $print_day3  = $rows['Day3'];
        $print_day4  = $rows['Day4'];
        $print_day5  = $rows['Day5'];
        $print_day6  = $rows['Day6'];
        $print_day7  = $rows['Day7'];
        $print_day8  = $rows['Day8'];
        $print_day9  = $rows['Day9'];
        $print_day10 = $rows['Day10'];
        $print_day11 = $rows['Day11'];
        $print_day12 = $rows['Day12'];
        $print_day13 = $rows['Day13'];
        $print_day14 = $rows['Day14'];


        }

    }
    require('/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph.php');
    require('/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph_line.php'); 

    //  data
    $ydata =       
array($print_day1,$print_day2,$print_day3,$print_day4,$print_day5,$print_day6,$print_day7,$print_day8,$print_day9);

// Create the graph. These two calls are always required
$graph = new Graph(500,500);
$graph->SetScale('textlin');
$graph->xaxis->title->Set("Number of Days");
$graph->yaxis->title->Set("Glucose Concentration");

// Create the linear plot
$lineplot=new LinePlot($ydata);
$lineplot->SetColor('blue');

// Add the plot to the graph
$graph->Add($lineplot);

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke();

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: _“it will become a broken image”_ – first of all, call the script via your browser’s address bar directly (not using `<img src=script.php>`). If you don’t see any error messages then, view the actual content the browser received in the network panel of your browser’s developer tools or something like FireBug.

Comment: @CBroe     when the php file has only the graph and no sessions or array from db it can be displayed as a separate page. But it does not show the graph when there are other php codes present which go hand-in-hand with it.

Comment: Then figure out _why_, please. I told you the basic steps of debugging by looking for error messages in your script’s output. If you don’t see any, check your PHP error reporting configuration. If still none – then it’s time to start debugging the script itself, using debug outputs of variable values and comparing them to the expected values.